# Rails doesn't recognise my app/services (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, initialization, constants, gibbon

I am stuck and even if I found some subjects about this issue, I didn't found any solution.

I am trying to add a subscription to Mailchimp if my "Packer" register to our newsletter (A "Packer" is a kind of "User" - "User" only has the Devise parameters and "Packer" has the rest)

The error is an uninitialized constant, It seems to be because rails doesn't recognize my service.

Here is my #app/models/packer.rb

```
after_create :subscribe_to_newsletter
after_update :subscribe_to_newsletter
private
def subscribe_to_newsletter
  SubscribeToNewsletterService.new.call(self.user) if self.newsletter
end
```

and my # app/services/subscribe_to_newsletter_service.rb

```
require "gibbon"
class SubscribeToNewsletterService
  def initialize
    @gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
    @list_id = ENV['MAILCHIMP_NEWSLETTER_LIST_ID']
  end
  def call(user)
    @gibbon.lists(@list_id).members.create(
      body: {
        email_address: user.email,
        status: "subscribed",
        double_optin: false,
        # merge_fields: {
        #   FNAME: @user.first_name,
        #   LNAME: @user.last_name
        # }
      }
    )
  end
end
```

Looking into the different solutions, I also added that line in #config/application.rb

```
module Pyswebsitev1
  class Application < Rails::Application
    @config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en
  end
end
```

When I do a rails console - ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
The result include /app/services

```
"/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/assets",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/channels",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/controllers",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/controllers/concerns",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/helpers",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/jobs",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/mailers",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/models",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/models/concerns",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/policies",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/app/services",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails-assets-underscore-1.8.3/app/assets",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.7/app/assets",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/attachinary-98a895be22ed/app/controllers",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/app/assets",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/app/controllers",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/app/helpers",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.2/app/assets",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.2/app/helpers",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/helpers",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/mailers",
 "/Users/MaxBook/code/PackYourSkills/pyswebsitev1/test/mailers/previews"
```

I also tried to "Spring stop", to reboot server, and to bundle.

If you have any idea, that would be very helpfull !
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to put the `_service` in your filename event if you put it in your question. Just guessing ...

Answer (score 0):

Your forget the `_service` at the end of the filename.